# Spring - ehcache doesn't work propertly

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I have a problem with ehcache in my application. I want to store in cache two method that has two diferent queries to db. The problem is that the data of second method is stored in data of first method and when the user make multiple request the data is duplicated everytime.

For example:

- First call ->

  - method 1 return 0 items
  - method 2 return 2 items
- Second call -> The methods are cached and just return the stored data but...

  - method 1 return 2 items ¿?
  - method 2 return 2 items
- Third call ->

  - method 1 return 4 items ¿?
  - method 2 return 2 items

Dao class:

```
public class DataDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements DataDAO {
  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1;

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2;

  @PostConstruct
  private void initialize() {
      setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate1);
  }

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;


  @Cacheable("data_1")
  public List<Data> getData1(String data, String start_date, String end_date) {
      List<Data> list_data_1 = (List<Data>) jdbcTemplate1.query(
            env.getProperty("sql_data_1"),
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Data.class), 
            data, start_date, end_date);
      return list_data_1;
  }

  @Cacheable("data_2")
  public List<Data> getData2(String data, String start_date, String end_date) {
      List<Data> list_data_2 = (List<Data>) jdbcTemplate2.query(
            env.getProperty("sql_data_2"),
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Data.class), 
            data, start_date, end_date);
      return list_data_2;
  }
}
```

Main class:

```
List<Data> arrayData = new ArrayList<Data>();   
arrayData = dataDAO.getData1(data, start_date, end_date);
arrayData.addAll(dataDAO.getData2(data, start_date, end_date));
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caching works fine, the problem is what you do with the result returned.

```
List<Data> arrayData = new ArrayList<Data>();   
arrayData = dataDAO.getData1(data, start_date, end_date);
arrayData.addAll(dataDAO.getData2(data, start_date, end_date));
```

The code above updates the collection, without doing any defensive copy. Since you are most likely caching on heap, you are effectively modifying the content of what is cached.

So either you do the defensive copy before merging the collections:

```
List<Data> arrayData = new ArrayList<Data>(dataDAO.getData1(data, start_date, end_date));
arrayData.addAll(dataDAO.getData2(data, start_date, end_date));
```

or Ehcache has configuration options so that it is the cache doing a copy for you each time something is read from the cache - see [documentation for version 2.x](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.3/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-pattrn_copy_cache.html) and [documentation for version 3.x](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/serializers-copiers.html#copiers).

Note that the code above is not `null` safe.